# ios Swift GCM registration token nil

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging, appdelegate

What am I doing wrong? It prints out that my registrationToken is NIL although it also prints out Registration to GCM with success.

**appDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import SlideMenuControllerSwift
import AFNetworking

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var connectedToGCM = false
    var subscribedToTopic = false
    var gcmSenderID: String?
    var registrationToken: String?
    var registrationOptions = [String: AnyObject]()

    let registrationKey = "onRegistrationCompleted"
    let messageKey = "onMessageReceived"
    let subscriptionTopic = "/topics/global"


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        var configureError:NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
        if configureError != nil {
            println("Error configuring the Google context: \(configureError)")
        }
        gcmSenderID = GGLContext.sharedInstance().configuration.gcmSenderID
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        // Register for remote notifications
        var types: UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
        var settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings( forTypes: types, categories: nil )
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // [START start_gcm_service]
        GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(GCMConfig.defaultConfig())

        AFNetworkReachabilityManager.sharedManager().startMonitoring()
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        Utilities.customizeNavigationBar()
        Utilities.customizeNavigationBarButtons()
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MenuStoryboard", bundle: nil)
        let containerController: RestaurantTableViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("hi") as! RestaurantTableViewController
        let rightMenu: RightMenuViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("rightMenu") as! RightMenuViewController
        let leftMenu: LeftMenuViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("leftMenu") as! LeftMenuViewController


        let nvc: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: containerController)
        //        leftMenu.mainViewController = nvc

        let slideMenuController = SlideMenuController(mainViewController:nvc, leftMenuViewController: leftMenu, rightMenuViewController: rightMenu)
        self.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
    func application( application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData ) {

        // Start the GGLInstanceID shared instance with the default config and request a registration token to enable reception of notifications
        GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(GGLInstanceIDConfig.defaultConfig())
        registrationOptions = [kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
            kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:true]
        GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID, scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)


    }

    // [START receive_apns_token_error]
    func application( application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError
        error: NSError ) {
            println("Registration for remote notification failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            // [END receive_apns_token_error]
            let userInfo = ["error": error.localizedDescription]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
                registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
    }


    func registrationHandler(registrationToken: String!, error: NSError!) {
        if (registrationToken != nil) {
            self.registrationToken = registrationToken
            println("Registration Token: \(registrationToken)")
              NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(registrationToken, forKey: "registrationToken")
            self.subscribeToTopic()
            let userInfo = ["registrationToken": registrationToken]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
                self.registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
        } else {
            println("Registration to GCM failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            let userInfo = ["error": error.localizedDescription]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
                self.registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
        }    }
    func onTokenRefresh() {
        // A rotation of the registration tokens is happening, so the app needs to request a new token.
        println("The GCM registration token needs to be changed.")
        GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,
            scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)
    }

    func subscribeToTopic() {
        // If the app has a registration token and is connected to GCM, proceed to subscribe to the
        // topic
        if(registrationToken != nil && connectedToGCM) {
            GCMPubSub.sharedInstance().subscribeWithToken(self.registrationToken, topic: subscriptionTopic,
                options: nil, handler: {(NSError error) -> Void in
                    if (error != nil) {
                        // Treat the "already subscribed" error more gently
                        if error.code == 3001 {
                            print("Already subscribed to \(self.subscriptionTopic)")
                        } else {
                            print("Subscription failed: \(error.localizedDescription)");
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.subscribedToTopic = true;
                        NSLog("Subscribed to \(self.subscriptionTopic)");
                    }
            })
        }
    }

    // [START connect_gcm_service]
    func applicationDidBecomeActive( application: UIApplication) {
        // Connect to the GCM server to receive non-APNS notifications
        GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler({
            (NSError error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print("Could not connect to GCM: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                self.connectedToGCM = true
                print("Connected to GCM")
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                self.subscribeToTopic()
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        })
    }


    // [START ack_message_reception]
    func application( application: UIApplication,
        didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
            print("Notification received: \(userInfo)")
            // This works only if the app started the GCM service
            GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
            // Handle the received message
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil,
                userInfo: userInfo)
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }

    func application( application: UIApplication,
        didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
        fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
            print("Notification received: \(userInfo)")
            // This works only if the app started the GCM service
            GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
            // Handle the received message
            // Invoke the completion handler passing the appropriate UIBackgroundFetchResult value
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil,
                userInfo: userInfo)
            handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        GCMService.sharedInstance().disconnect()
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        self.connectedToGCM = false
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
        println("Stop executing app and whent into background!")
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }


    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


    // [START upstream_callbacks]
    func willSendDataMessageWithID(messageID: String!, error: NSError!) {
        if (error != nil) {
            // Failed to send the message.
        } else {
            // Will send message, you can save the messageID to track the message
        }
    }

    func didSendDataMessageWithID(messageID: String!) {
        // Did successfully send message identified by messageID
    }
    // [END upstream_callbacks]

    func didDeleteMessagesOnServer() {
        // Some messages sent to this device were deleted on the GCM server before reception, likely
        // because the TTL expired. The client should notify the app server of this, so that the app
        // server can resend those messages.
    }
}
```

**Error LOG**

```
Tracking ID must not be nil or empty.
Client ID must not be nil or empty.
Attempted to configure [Identity, Analytics, AdMob, SignIn, AppInvite, CloudMessaging].
Successfully configured [CloudMessaging].
Failed to configure [Analytics, SignIn].
Subspecs not present, so not configured [Identity, AdMob, AppInvite].

Error configuring the Google context: Optional(Error Domain=com.google.greenhouse Code=-200 "Unable to configure GGL." 
UserInfo=0x7fdab9d3a390 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Check formatting and location of GoogleService-Info.plist., NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to configure GGL., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to parse supplied GoogleService-Info.plist. See log for details.})
```

I'm trying to connect to GCM and I have already set SENDER-ID and SENDER ID its ok, what's wrong now?

[Setting up a GCM Client App on iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client?ver=swift)  it says:

> If registration was successful, InstanceID invokes the
>   registrationToken handler with a **valid registration token and a nil
>   error object**. If registration instead fails, the registration token is
>   nil and a valid error object is returned. For details on the error
>   codes, see GGLInstanceID.h. When registration fails, client apps
>   should implement exponential backoff to try again.

And I got in output a **nil error object** but also nil registration token.

Comment: Did you generate the `GoogleService-Info.plist` successfully from the [setup page](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client#get-config). Also your `AppDelegate` does not conform the `GGLInstanceIDDelegate` and `GCMReceiverDelegate`, you can check out the [GCM iOS sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/ios/gcm) from GitHub, especially the [AppDelegate](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/ios/gcm/GcmExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift) file.

Comment: Yes I have generated the `GoogleService-Info.plist` successfully but I don't know what to do for `GGLInstanceIDDelegate` and `GCMReceiverDelegate`. What prat of the GitHub project should I look at? Can you help me a little more because I'm really kind of new on this push and ios stuff..

Comment: Seems like there is an issue with your GoogleService-Info.plist, error says it is unable to parse it. Could you try going through the generation process again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is nothing wrong with your code, as this is the correct way to implement **Cloud Messaging** on **iOS Client**.

Some tricky parts that you might have missed are the configuration of the [Provisioning APNs SSL Certificates](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/certs)

1. Create your App ID with Push Notifications ON
2. Create your SSL Certificate
3. Download and run it in order to be added to the Provisioning Profile
4. To make sure that your provisioning profile has this certificate go to **Xcode -> Preferences -> Account -> Your Apple ID -> Your Team -> View Details -> Download All**.

This will refresh your certificates, and then go to your target, choose the correct team and run it. Hopefully it should work :)

Comment: Thank you! I was having issues with the certificates you mentioned here!